# Passing Data from Parent to Child Component's Input Field in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a personal project in React for the first time. It has a structure of the following form (the following is simplified):

```
const Parent = () => {
   
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Series of variables to hold the values from Child2
   }
   
   return (
   <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <div>
            <Child1 name="child1"/>
            <Child1 name="child2"/>
         </div>
         <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   );
}

const Child1 = () => {
   
   return (
   <div>
      <Child2 name="childchild1"/> // Child 2 components are individual inputs fields
      <Child2 name="childchild2"/>
      <Child2 name="childchild3"/>
   </div>
   );
}

const Child2 = () => {

   return (
   <div>
      <input type="number" .......></input>
   </div>
   );
}
```

Basically put, I would like to add an import button in my Parent component which will fill the fields found in the Child2 Components. My question is: How would I go about passing the values from my Parent component to my Child2 Components so that they fill their input fields? I am looking for a relatively clean solution if possible. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with having state in the parent and passing props to the children?

Comment: @caTS I'm not sure I can do that in this case. I need certain values to be passed down to input fields of the Child components upon the use of a function in the Parent component. What I am trying to do is importing a JSON file, then having the information within this file autofill the fields of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Component are build to be reusable. The clean way is to pass value from Child2 to Parent through Child 1.

```
const Parent = () => {
  
   const [state1, setState1] = useState({}) 
   const [state2, setState2] = useState({}) 
  
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Series of variables to hold the values from Child2
   }
   
   return (
   <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <div>
            <Child1 value={state1} onChange={setState1} name="child1"/>
            <Child1 value={state2} onChange={setState2} name="child2"/>
         </div>
         <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   );
}

const Child1 = ({ value, onChange }) => {
   
   return (
   <div>
      <Child2 value={value.substate1} onChange={v=>onChange({...value, substate1: v})} name="childchild1"/> // Child 2 components are individual inputs fields
      <Child2 value={value.substate2} onChange={v=>onChange({...value, substate2: v})} name="childchild2"/>
      <Child2 value={value.substate3} onChange={v=>onChange({...value, substate3: v})} name="childchild3"/>
   </div>
   );
}

const Child2 = ({ value, onChange }) => {

   return (
   <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={onChange} type="number" .......></input>
   </div>
   );
}
```

If that answer is unacceptable for you, you can have a look to redux or react context, but that breaks the reusability of the component and thats not "clean"

Comment: I believe this is more focused on transmitting values from Child2 up to Parent. How would this be different if I want to do the opposite? For example, I would like to take a value found in my Parent component, and then send it to a specific input field of a Child2 component.

Comment: Tend to say, the same way you pass the value as a props.